# TCP/IP Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I have been trying and searched thousands of times in other sites but never found a sample or simple code to use.

I've created an application C# which uses an ODBC connection, i have also MS SQL installed and configured to enable remoting database information sharing. I want to make my database available to everyone uses this application i have made by using a connection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CaseMatter
{

public partial class mainLog : Form
{
    string userID, userName, userAddress, userFName, userLastName, userCity, userPassword, userTele;
    public mainLog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Size = new Size(442, 162);

    }


    private void Submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string ConnectionString =
              "Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            var strSQLCommand = "SELECT Name FROM example WHERE id='1'";
            var command = new SqlCommand(strSQLCommand, conn);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                passwordBox.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

    }
}
```

}

I have just edited the code and tried it, i have added a try catch to handle sql exceptions but it still freezes when i click on submit button.

Hopefully someone figures this out.
ERROR:
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)"

Comment: Please post the precise exception you're receiving. Looks like probably a security problem, since you're not specifying login credentials.

Comment: I dont receive any error or such problems before compiling the project but after compiling it, the frameworks freezes

Comment: It's unclear what's going wrong here.  Are you getting an exception, bad data, etc ...

Comment: i dont get any problem unless the project is compiled and then BANG! freeze xD have no idea iam a very newbie

Comment: For starters, insert prints into your code to find out where it freezes (or run it in the debugger).  Then come back and let us know where the freeze occurs.

Comment: conn.open(); here is the problem, i did just as you said, and it referred to this break point

Comment: Probably not important but that's not an ODBC connection its actually  the [.NET Framework Data Provider connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx)

Comment: been trying every possible type of connections but nothing is doing well. How would you all do if you want to setup an application with free access for all type of users from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are one of four things going on here.

1. The SQL Server is misconfigured and isn't responding to tcp connections.  The easiest way to trouble shoot this is to use SQL Management Studio to connect.  If you can't connect this way then you'll have to look at the sql server service setup.  Also, make sure that the SQL Browser service is running on the server.
2. The SQL Server is configured to use a different TCP port than the one you are trying.  Remove the ",1433" from your connection string and try again.  SQL Browser should respond back with the actual port that sql server is listening on.
3. The SQL Server has a firewall in place that is blocking remote connections.  Temporarily turn off the firewall and see if you can connect.  If you can, then configure the firewall correctly and turn it back on.
4. Your local box has some type of firewall that is blocking outgoing connections on that port.  Try turning yours off to see if this helps.  If so, configure it correctly and turn it back on.

---

If this is a brand new sql server that no one has remotely connected to then it's very likely to be entirely within the configuration of SQL server or the Windows configuration.

Comment: All good points. In addition to the earlier reported problem, based on the updated info from the OP, it looks more and more like a configuration issue.

Comment: I have tried to pass the port through firewall... but, Chris what do you mean by windows configuration

Comment: @Ivan: did you first try just completely disabling the firewall?  If you turn it off and can connect then we know it's a firewall issue.   By Windows config, I'm talking about the built in firewall to Windows.

Comment: @Ivan: make sure that SQL Browser is running.  Also, make sure that it is configured to enable TCP.  I believe both of which are off by default.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are not passing the USER ID and Password.  Is that just because you didnt want to include your credentials?  I assume not as you properly XXX out your IP address.  I would start by supplying credentials of a SQL server account that can access your database.

Comment: XXX= are my ip-adress numbers, but what about the user ID and password? do i really need to specify those aspects? where can i find them, or may i freely choose what to write?

Comment: They must correspond to an account configured on the SQL server box you are connecting too.

Comment: Hmm, when i try to connect to MS SQL i use windows Auth... so i dont really specify... in that box i see only the user name (Pc-Pc\PC), if it can be solve by few steps can you please write them to me. so i can follow your guide.

Comment: @Ivan look at [trusted connection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

Comment: in your connection string change it to read:Data Source=XX.XX.XX.XX,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=True

Comment: I have done that but still freezing :( at conn.open(); i updated the code to the whole class code.

Comment: so you can connect to the server using windows auth in enterprise manager?

Comment: I log into the SQL server with windows auth. i get now the following error
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Comment: by default sql server is configured to use named pipes, since you are trying to connect using tcp/ip have you in fact configured sql server to listen on tcp/ip?  This is some info for configuring tcp/ip http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using `SqlConnection` which is not an ODBC connection object. With `SqlConnection` you're actually connecting via ADO.NET. The connection string syntax for `SqlConnection` (both ODBC and ADO.NET) can be found on the following site:

http://connectionstrings.com

By the way, if you're connecting to SQL 2005, the connection string would look like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// trusted connection (SQL configured to use your windows ID)
string ConnectionString = 
  "Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

// sql authentication (SQL manages its own users/pwds)
//string ConnectionString = 
  //"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

var strSQLCommand = "SELECT Name from [example_autoincrement] where id='1'";     
var command = new SqlCommand(strSQLCommand, conn);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{   
    passwordBox.Text = reader.GetString(0);
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: I have been trying diffrent strings but seems like the problem is not in the code, because everyone is answering like "the same" so it might be somewhere else in configuring maybe...


I did the following steps to configure my ms sql 2005

1- sql server configure 
2- client protocols (all enabled)

Comment: That's also possible. Does the osql client work? Or better yet, have you tried running the Query Analyzer to connect? If these don't work, then you may be facing a configuration issue.

Comment: Already tried to allow the SQL passing the firewall and gave full access to every user but still facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a strange one to check but just make sure the time and date is accurate on client and server. SSPI requires a maximum gap of 5 minutes between each

Comment: Ahm... how do i find this out :) as said before i am a newbie programmer.

Comment: Well, just look on the client machine and make sure the time and timezone are correct (control panel), then log into the server and do the same. If i remember rightly i get this error when our development virtual servers get powered down and the time doesn't update when it boots back up.

Comment: Everything is fine with timezone